# How to include files properly?

Tags: angular

I have problem with routing becuase i am using laravel as backed and i found post where they added this:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy,
}
from '@angular/common';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

But im getting errors for this that they dont have exported member:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
```

Also i get error for this:

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
```

Any suggestion how can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This usage,

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
```

is for deprecated router(beta). We now have `@NgModule` and router specific module

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Follow the latest documentation on: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/